# Change font in just one tabular / section to sans-serif

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I don't think it's difficult but I got no right answer on google, so I have to asked here:

How to change the font to sans-serif for just one section or the tabular. And  I also need the right way to change it back after the tabular, I don't want to use another font, because there should be three default fonts in LaTeX?

My LaTeX code is super simple:

```
\section{2. Section}
    \begin{tabular}{| c c c c c c c c c c}
    ...
    \end{tabular}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!  Can you try the following code: `{ \sffamily \begin{tabular}....\end{tabular} }` ? (the `{ }` around everything will restrict the font change to just this group, so you don't have to worry about changing the font back afterwards)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Tex.sx! Please always provide a full minimal working example (MWE) https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that when posting a question here. This is quite a basic question. Have a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font%20sizes,%20families,%20and%20styles for choosing a sans-serif for a part of your text. For example use: `\textsf{Sample Text 0123}` within your tabular or do like @samcarter said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the font to sans serife you can use command `\sffamily`.

To make sure that only your tabular uses the other font simply enclose command `\sffamily` and your table with `{...}`. That means that after the closing `}` the old font before `{` is used again.

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
text text text text text
{\sffamily % <===========================================================
\section{2. Section}
\begin{tabular}{| c c c c c c c c c c}
  test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test \\
  test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test \\
\end{tabular}
} % <====================================================================
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image]